# Scala contiguous match

Tags: scala

```
pathTokens match {
 case List("post") => ("post", "index")
 case List("search") => ("search", "index")
 case List() => ("home", "index")
} match {
 case (controller, action) => loadController(http, controller, action)
 case _ => null
}
```

I wanted contiguous match. but got compile error. :(

```
(pathTokens match {
 case List("post") => ("post", "index")
 case List("search") => ("search", "index")
 case List() => ("home", "index")
}) match {
 case (controller, action) => loadController(http, controller, action)
 case _ => null
}
```

When I wrapped first match with parenparenthesis, it worked ok.
Why I need parenthesis here ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's how the Scala syntax is defined. Please have a look at the specification:
http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf

There you will find the following definition (p. 153, shortened for clarity):

```
Expr1 ::= PostfixExpr 'match' '{' CaseClauses '}'
```

If you dig into `PostfixExpr` you will eventually find `SimpleExpr1` which contains the following definition:

```
SimpleExpr1 ::= '(' [Exprs [',']] ')'
Exprs ::= Expr {',' Expr}
```

That means that `SimpleExpr1` (and thus `PostfixExpr`) can only contain other expressions (like 'x match y') when they are wrapped in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Not what you want, but you can do stuff like this:

```
val f1 = (_: List[String]) match {
 case List("post") => ("post", "index")
 case List("search") => ("search", "index")
 case List() => ("home", "index")
}

val f2 = (_: (String, String)) match {
 case (controller, action) => loadController(http, controller, action)
}

(f1 andThen f2)(pathTokens)
```